# How do I create a year-only drop-down field?

Tags: 8, entities

How do I create a year-only drop-down field?

I want to create a Drupal 8 field that shows a year drop-down with 100 years to the current year.

Answer (score 4):

The [Year Only](https://www.drupal.org/project/yearonly) module provides this feature by defining a new field type.

[image: Year only field type].

It comes with a range configuration.

[image: Year only range configuration]

It produces the following result in the entity (node, ...) edit form. Configured with unlimited number of values in this example.

[image: Year only values]

Answer (score -1):

I would personally recommend following https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/242011/5438. It's a little more work with some coding but it doesn't mean you need to add another module that needs to be supported in relation to many drupal areas. You can use a List (integer) field and add things there.

You can can also use a field_integer textfield and use a form alterer.

Comment: The link suggests creating a custom module so I don't see the benefit here?

Comment: @DanielHarper it's a helper module that uses a core API hook, this means you will hardly have to update it and it uses core's field types instead of one provided by a module. The level of maintainability is considerable less IMO. I did say it was a personal recommendation, this is the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module.

> This package contains both a flexible date/time field type Date field
>   and a Date API that other modules can use.

When you add field you can choose what you want to show (day, month, year) and + and - from current year.

Comment: This was only the case for the D7 module. Date in core does not have these options.