# Basefield 'string' shown as select list widget in entity form

Tags: 8, plugins

I've got a custom entity ('content_sharing') and defined one of the fields as `$fields['entity_definition'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')...`. The create-form I'm showing the user is loaded with an empty entity via a controller like so:

```
    $contentSharing = $this->entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('content_sharing')
      ->create([]);
    $form = $this->entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('content_sharing', 'custom_mode')
      ->setEntity($contentSharing);
    $output['form'] = $this->formBuilder()->getForm($form);
    ...
```

What I need now is to present the user a select-list of possible strings (options) that are dynamically pre-populated everytime the form is loaded. The only `FieldWidget` for string fields is a textfield. I tried to come up with my own custom FieldWidget similar to this

```
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "string_select_list",
 *   module = "content_sharing",
 *   label = @Translation("Select list for strings"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "string"
 *   },
 *  multiple_values = FALSE
 * )
 */

class StringSelectList extends OptionsWidgetBase {
```

However, this resulted in an error and I  noticed that this needs to have options defined which I cannot (don't know how to) provide for my string basefield.

I could of cource just add a dummy form-element select list that provides the values for my entity field, but I wanted to use the entityform as it is without any further custom elements.

Possible with a custom widget or any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a list_string base field and use as widget OptionsSelectWidget.

```
$fields['entity_definition'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
  ->setLabel(t('Entity Definition'))
  ->setSettings([
    'allowed_values' => [
      'value1' => 'Value 1',
      'value2' => 'Value 2',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'options_select',
  ])
```

To update the options dynamically add a callback to the base field settings `allowed_values_function`, see [How do I programmatically update the allowed values of a list field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242006/how-do-i-programmatically-update-the-allowed-values-of-a-list-field)

Comment: I thought about that too, but was hesitant because of having to update the allowed values every time. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I guess that passing an argument other than `FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $definition, FieldableEntityInterface $entity` is impossible...? Just asking since the options of one of the fields depends on the selected value of another form-field.

Comment: Found a way. I'm calculating all possible allowed values in `allowed_values_function`, then getting those values inside my `buildForm()` via `$options = options_allowed_values($fields['field_id']);`and creating a subset of those, dependent on another form fields selected value. Works well. Thanks!