# Programmatically add values in a select field: issues when submitting

Tags: forms, 9

I'm inserting some options in the #options element of the select render array:

```php
foreach ($files['files'] as $file) {
    $form['field_session_row']['widget'][0]['subform'][$field_name]['widget']['#options'][$file['ll_id']] = $file['ll_name'];
}
```

This ends in an error under the select:

```
The value you selected is not a valid choice.
```

I've also tried to set the `#validated` element to `TRUE` and unsetting the `#element_validate` in order to bypass the form element validation.
However, when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::massageFormValues(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in /var/www/vhosts/newEcmwf/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php on line 400 in Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->massageFormValues() (line 547 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php).
```

Dumping `$values` it turns out `$values` when the error is triggered is `_none`.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Code:
Code (optimized and changed compared to the other thread):

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
 *
 * @noinspection PhpUnusedParameterInspection
 * @noinspection PhpUnused
 * @noinspection UnusedFunctionResultInspection
 */
function livelink_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id): void {
    if ($form_id === 'node_committee_session_form' || $form_id === 'node_committee_session_edit_form') {
        foreach ($form as $field_id => $field) {
            if (preg_match('/^field_livelink_field_document_..$/', $field_id)) {
                $id = Arr::get($form, "$field_id.widget.0.value.#default_value");
                Arr::set($form, "$field_id.widget.0.list-button", [
                  '#type' => 'button',
                  '#name' => "button_$field_id",
                  '#value' => !empty($id) ? t('Refresh') : t('List'),
                  '#attributes' => ['onclick' => 'return (false);'],
                  '#ajax' => [
                    'callback' => 'livelink_get_files_callback',
                    'wrapper' => "$field_id-folder-info",
                    'effect' => 'fade',
                    'related_field' => $field_id,
                    'select_field' => str_replace('field_livelink_', '', $field_id) . '_select'
                  ],
                ]);
                Arr::set($form, "$field_id.widget.0.folder-info-div", [
                  '#markup' => !empty($id) ? livelink_render_files_from_cache($id) : '',
                  '#prefix' => "<div id='$field_id-folder-info'>",
                  '#suffix' => '</div>',
                ]);
            }
        }


        $session_rows = Arr::where(Arr::get($form, 'field_session_row.widget'), fn ($item, $key) => is_int($key) && is_array($item));
        foreach ($session_rows as $index => $session_row) {
            $subform = &$form['field_session_row']['widget'][$index]['subform'];

            $fields = collect($subform)
              ->filter(fn($value, $field_name) => preg_match('/^field_document_.._select$/', $field_name));
            foreach ($fields as $field_name => $value) {
                $select = &$subform[$field_name]['widget'];
                $select['#prefix'] = "<div class='livelink-field-wrapper' id='{$field_name}_$index'>";
                $select['#suffix'] = '</div>';
                // Get files
                $field = str_replace('_select', '', $field_name);

                // Load files options
                $folder_id = Arr::get($form, "field_livelink_$field.widget.0.value.#default_value");
                if ($folder_id) {
                    $files = livelink_load_files_cache($folder_id);
                    foreach (array_column($files, 'll_name', 'll_id') as $id => $name) {
                        $select['#options'][(string) $id] = $name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * AJAX callback to trigger querying a file list from Livelink.
 *
 * @noinspection PhpUnused
 * @noinspection PhpUnusedParameterInspection
 */
function livelink_get_files_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, string $language): AjaxResponse {
    $ajax_info = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#ajax'];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();


    $id = $form_state->getValue($ajax_info['related_field'])[0]['value'];
    if ($id) {
        try {
            $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#' . $ajax_info['wrapper'], livelink_render_new_files($id)));
        } catch (GuzzleException) {
            return $response;
        }
        $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand("[name='{$form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name']}']", 'val', [t('Refresh')]));

        $response->addCommand(new MessageCommand('The file listing will not be saved until the page is saved.', null, ['type' => 'warning']));

        $files = livelink_load_files_cache($id);
        $files_options = array_column($files, 'll_name', 'll_id');

        $form_state->setRebuild();

        foreach ($form['field_session_row']['widget'] as $index => $widget) {
            if (is_int($index) && is_array($form['field_session_row']['widget'][$index])) {
                $select = $form['field_session_row']['widget'][$index]['subform'][$ajax_info['select_field']]['widget'];

                foreach ($files_options as $id => $name) {
                    $select['#options'][(string) $id] = $name;
                }
                $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("div.livelink-field-wrapper[id^='{$ajax_info['select_field']}']", $select));
            }
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Would you please also indicate which hook you are implementing? You are trying to modify the options in a select element of a form. Do I have that right?

Comment: @cilefen Yes, I'm using the form_alter hook. Yes, you are right: I'm trying to add custom/dynamic options to a select

Comment: Dynamic? Is this using the form Ajax API? I think we would need to see more of your code as this site isn’t good for interviewing.

Comment: For dynamic I mean custom options loaded with PHP/AJAX and added to #options

Comment: I'm guessing you added the options in an #ajax callback. This will not work. Any form options need to be defined in the form definition, as the form has already been cached by the time the #ajax callback happens.

Comment: No, the code you see in the OP where I'm editing the form is in the form_alter hook

Comment: I have voted to close this issue until we have *all* the code, because this has become an interview.

Comment: @cilefen I've added the full form_alter hook and ajax callback code to the OP

Comment: Your ajax callback is probably not returning the Drupal settings with the returned values. But It's not clear what you're trying to do with the callback, and why you aren't returning part of the form array (as is standard). When done this way, Drupal will also send the updating settings for the form, required for any new ajax enabled elements.

Comment: @Jaypan see here for the updated code where I return the form array: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/313234/adding-options-to-a-select-via-ajax-an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected

Comment: No, you're returning an AjaxResponse, not an array. And please keep your code to one thread, I'm working off the code above.

Comment: @Jaypan I've updated the code above. As you can see I return the form array in the replacecommand because I have to do multiple commands. Shall I do something similar or I have to return only the form array with the options changed? If yes, how can I keep the MessageCommand?

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: "As you can see I return the form array in the replacecommand" which means you are returning a replacecommand, not an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was in this comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/264719/108326
Basically you have to override the allowed_values function of the field and set the new options