# Custom Field Type Checkboxes

Tags: 9

I'm trying to create a custom FieldType. I've found many example with a textfield. But I want a custom field with checkboxes. I'm having a hard time finding an example like that.

If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

I have the field made, correct options showing up. I'm currently stuck with the incorrect primitive type. I'm not sure how to set this up properly.

[image: edit page]

Here's my code for the FieldType, FieldWidget and config.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\field_active_bundles\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_active_bundles' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "field_active_bundles",
 *   label = @Translation("Active Bundles"),
 *   module = "field_active_bundles",
 *   category = "Custom",
 *   description = @Translation("Selects active bundles for component."),
 *   default_widget = "field_active_bundles_widget",
 *   default_formatter = "field_active_bundles_formatter"
 * )
 */
class ActiveBundles extends FieldItemBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return [
      'columns' => [
        'value' => [
          'type' => 'text',
          'size' => 'tiny',
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isEmpty() {
    $value = $this->get('value')->getValue();
    return $value === NULL || $value === '';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties['value'] = DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('What ever'));
    return $properties;
  }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\field_active_bundles\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_active_bundles' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "field_active_bundles_widget",
 *   module = "field_active_bundles",
 *   label = @Translation("Default checkboxes"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "field_active_bundles"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ActiveBundlesWidget extends WidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $bundle_info = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('entity_product');

    foreach ($bundle_info as $key => $value) {
      $options[$key] = $value['label'];
    }

    $element['value'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => 'Active Bundles',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#element_validate' => [
        [$this, 'validate'],
      ],
    ];

    if ($element['#required']) {
      $element[$key]['#required'] = TRUE;
    }

    return ['value' => $element];
  }

  /**
   * Validate the fields and convert them into a single value as text.
   */
  public function validate($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // TBD.
  }

}
```

```
# @see Configuration schema/metadata at https://drupal.org/node/1905070
field.field_active_bundles.value:
  type: sequence
  label: 'Default value'
  sequence:
    - type: mapping
      label: 'Default'
      mapping:
        value:
          type: string
          label: 'Value'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only custom requirement is providing dynamic checkboxes items. You could use the core field list type and provide the options in this callback:

*mymodule.module*

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;

function mymodule_allowed_values_function(FieldStorageConfig $definition, ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL, $cacheable) {
  $options = [];
  $bundle_info = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('entity_product');
  foreach ($bundle_info as $key => $value) {
    $options[$key] = $value['label'];
  }
  return $options;
}
```

See [How do I programmatically update the allowed values of a list field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242006/how-do-i-programmatically-update-the-allowed-values-of-a-list-field)

However, for this specific case there is a UI-only solution by adding a multi-value reference field for other entities and then specifying the config entity for the product bundles.